# Can't change INDEXBY for findAll() and findBy() functions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

With Doctrine and Symfony 5, I want to change INDEX BY for my queries with `findAll()` and `findBy()` functions. I would like the keys of the result table to be simply the IDs.

```
// Current result
[
    0 => Post {
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Test 5',
    },
    1 => Post {
        'id' => 6,
        'name' => 'Test 6',
    },
]
// Desired result :
[
    5 => Post {
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Test 5',
    },
    6 => Post {
        'id' => 6,
        'name' => 'Test 6',
    },
]
```

I know that I can use `createQueryBuilder('post', 'post.id')`, but in this case I lose the `fetch = EAGER` since I make the queries myself.

Maybe the only solution is to do foreach () to change the keys of each `findAll()` and `findBy()` request, but I find it heavy.

Comment: You're leaking view details into your model. A red light bulb should start blinking that you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the `findBy` method or `findAll` method:

Create a foreach `($results as $result)` as follows:

```
$newResult = [];
$results = $repo->findAll();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $newResult[$result->getId()] = $result;
}
```

Comment: Yes I had considered this solution as I indicated at the end of my post. There is no better solution than doing `foreach ()` with each `findBy` and `findAll` ?

Comment: You can surcharge findBy or findAll into your repository. I don't think better solution.